# can I install wamp twice in different folders?

Tags: yii, wamp, yiic

I'm facing a problem due to the folder name "Program Files" in which my wamp is installed.
I'm using Yii Framework to create a web app.
While running a command

**yiic webapp c:\Program Files\wamp\www\YiiApp**

it gives error due to the white space in the folder name.
The error is as below:

```
C:\Program Files\wamp\www\yii-1.1.13.e9e4a0\framework>yiic webapp c:\Program Fil
es\wamp\www\YiiApp
Error: Unsupported VCS specified. Currently only git and hg supported.

USAGE
  yiic webapp <app-path> [<vcs>]

DESCRIPTION
  This command generates an Yii Web Application at the specified location.

PARAMETERS
 * app-path: required, the directory where the new application will be created.
   If the directory does not exist, it will be created. After the application
   is created, please make sure the directory can be accessed by Web users.
 * vcs: optional, version control system you're going to use in the new project.

   Application generator will create all needed files to the specified VCS
   (such as .gitignore, .gitkeep, etc.). Possible values: git, hg. Do not
   use this argument if you're going to create VCS files yourself.
```

What should I do? Please suggest me something.

Comment: Tried to install wamp in different folder & run the command from that folder. Its working. No problem.

Comment: Did you try with quotes? `yiic webapp "c:\Program Files\wamp\www\YiiApp"`.

Answer (score 0):

The second install will have superceeded the first. In other words Wampmanager and Apache and MySQL will be being started out of the new folder.

As per your question on wamp forum, copy wwww/subfolders into the new location and then copy ONLY YOUR databases from mysqlx.y.z/data into the same place in the new location.

Then delete the folders from program files.

You only need one wamp ( Apache/MySQL) per system.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something else:
Without moving the previously installed wamp's content just read the

> "uninstall_services.bat"  file

just uninstall these services from that wamp directory which you want to disable.

Still the another wamp's services won't start. So install those services mentioned in "uninstall_services.bat" file manually from respective directories.
Now Restart All Services from the tray icon. The required wamp will be enabled.

If won't, try it again. No need to reinstall wamp.